# how to replace names of files from another folder?

Tags: r

I have 4 files in a folder `dir1` and other 4 files in another `dir2`

We can list files in both folders as:

```
dir1<- list.files("/data/myfiles1", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
dir1
file_data_20000125.img
file_data_20000126.img
file_data_20000127.img
file_data_20000128.img

dir2<- list.files("/data/myfiles2", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
newfile_01.img
newfile_02.img
newfile_03.img
newfile_04.img
```

Now what I need is to just to replace the the names of the files in `dir2` by the names of files in `dir1`. For instance, `newfile_01.img`  becomes `file_data_20000125.img`,
`newfile_02.img`  becomes `file_data_20000126.img`,
and so on.

Comment: file.rename() would appear to do just this. Have you tried it?

Comment: Then I do not know what you want. You want the names of the files to be replaced with new names, right? Isn't that just renaming?

Comment: @MikeWise  How we can relate dir1 and dir2 using `file.rename()`

Comment: Is you requirement to change the file name as per the file names in the other folder

Comment: is there same amount of file in both the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it there may be more faster way

`basename` is used to get base name from the full fie path and I am using `gsub`to replace the onld filename with the new filename

`file.rename` is used to replace the file name

**My code:**

```
dir1<- list.files("/data/myfiles1", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
dir2<- list.files("/data/myfiles2", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
for (a in 1:length(dir1)){
    file.rename(from=dir2[a],to=gsub(basename(dir2[a]),basename(dir1[a]),dir2[a]))
}
```